# What is the Lowest point of gravity on the Earth map?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, earth

what is the **lowest** `gravity` point on the earth **surface** and where is it exactly **on the map** and what is the importance of having low gravity on earth surface...

Comment: [Gravity map reveals Earth's extremes](https://www.newscientist.com/article/dn24068-gravity-map-reveals-earths-extremes/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too narrow in scope and might not be helpful to future visitors.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/22613/2451

Answer (score 5):

Here is a map of the gravity field of earth [given by NASA](https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/GRACE/page3.php)

[image: nasa gravity field]

> Earth's gravity measured by NASA GRACE mission, showing deviations from the theoretical gravity of an idealized smooth Earth, the so-called Earth ellipsoid. Red shows the areas where gravity is stronger than the smooth, standard value, and blue reveals areas where gravity is weaker.

So one would have to look for the deepest blue color in this map and wait for more accurate data. Here is an [animated version .](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:GRACE_globe_animation.gif)

There is a blue region  in the [indian ocean,](https://phys.org/news/2017-10-masswhat-geoid-indian-ocean.html)

> These highs and lows are generated by uneven mass distribution within the deep Earth.
>
> One such point of low gravity is found just south of the Indian peninsula, called the Indian Ocean Geoid Low (IOGL). The geoid low spans a vast extent south of the Indian subcontinent, and is dominated by a significant low of minus 106 metres, or roughly 348 feet, south of Sri Lanka.

But it is one of the low points, as deep blue can be seen in the map in many places, although it is treated as the "lowest" point in the publication linked above.

This is an ongoing research measurement, and the accuracy might increase in the future so as to pick a "lowest"point of gravity, but at the moment there are many "lowest" according to the map.

edit.

The maps are from 2004. [A later study](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/grl.50838) ,2013,

> GGMplus reveals a candidate location for the minimum gravity acceleration on Earth: the Nevado Huascarán summit (Peru) with an estimated acceleration of $9.76392 m s^−2$

Comment: "So one would have to look for the deepest blue color in this map". This is not correct statement, because he asks about *absolute* scale, not a scale relative to an ellipsoid. If gravity means also centrifugal pseudoforce, then the answer is almost surely some place near equator. I would believe it might be Chimborazo https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chimborazo EDIT: Here is an element of answer also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Variation_in_magnitude

Comment: @F.Jatpil  It is an abolute scale , it is +/-  of the  gravitational acceleration  at sea level for the model assumed. anyway I have given  quotes to later  measurements.

Comment: "showing deviations from the theoretical gravity of an idealized smooth Earth, the so-called Earth ellipsoid"

Answer (score 0):

If you mean by your question the measured acceleration of a free falling object then the lowest acceleration is almost certainly on some high peak near equator because 2 factors are in favour of that:

1) Earth is ellipsoid so places on equator are more distant from Earth center then places on poles (and gravity decreases with distance).

2) Centrifugal (pseudo)force acts in the opposite direction as gravity and places on equator rotate the most, i.e. with most acceleration (any place on earth has the same angular speed, and from points with same angular speed those with the largest distance from the center experience most acceleration).

As mentioned in a different answer a hot candidate is Huascaran. Yet, I believe it is in reality Chimborazo, because both factors play in its favour: it is more distant from Earth center then Huascaran and it is closer to Equator (centrifugal force) - these are fairly trivial and valid arguments. Uness some very different rock densities are under Huascaran vs. Chimborazo, Chimborazo has to be the winner.